# Sass is processed wrongfully inside a react app

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Can't really explain but once you see the sass and css you'll know what I'm talking about.

my sass:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:ital,wght@0,500;0,600;0,700;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Montserrat+Alternates:ital,wght@0,500;0,600;0,700;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap')

$font-primary: 'Barlow', sans-serif
$font-secondary: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif

.App
    background-color: #ffffff
    font-family: $font-secondary
    width: 100%
    min-height: 100vh


.Home, .Products, .About
    min-height: 100vh
    font-family: $font-primary
    text-align: center
    display: grid
    align-items: center
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr 1fr


.SwitchTab 
    color: #ffffff
    padding: 50px 0
    background-color: green
    font-family: $font-secondary
```

my css (compiled):

```
.App {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color-font-family: "Montserrat Alternates", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh; }

.Home, .Products, .About {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height-font-family: "Barlow", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr 1fr; }

.SwitchTab {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: green;
  background-color-font-family: "Montserrat Alternates", sans-serif; }
```

I've used sass and scss before and this has never happened to me. Anyone knows why or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code snippet you posted on The Odin Project Discord channel, this seems to be due to the indentation you have left out of the code snippet in your question here:

[image: Code snippet showing faulty processing]

And with the identations removed:

[image: Fixed processing]

Comment: Commenting for anyone seeing this in the future. The problem came from vim, the indentation was a tab + 1 space which is what caused trouble. I changed it to just 2 spaces and now it works flawlessly.
This is what I added to my vimrc:  

`set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.App
    background-color: #ffffff
    font-family: #{$font-secondary}
    width: 100%
    min-height: 100vh


.Home, .Products, .About
    min-height: 100vh
    font-family: #{$font-primary}
    text-align: center
    display: grid
    align-items: center
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr 1fr


.SwitchTab 
    color: #ffffff
    padding: 50px 0
    background-color: green
    font-family: #{$font-secondary}
```